# Which subfolders of $HOME should I put on a scratch disk, and which on a backed-up one?

Tags: backup, disk-usage, directory-structure, home

On my computer at work I have Fedora 24 installed (not my choice). My home folder is NFS-mounted and backed up routinely. I also have a pretty large local disk which is not backed up.

Now, I've been requested to cut down on the size of my home directory and keep it to under 10 GB. So - I've started "moving parts of my home folder" to the local disk, i.e. if before I had `$HOME/.ccache`, I now have a `/mnt/sdb1/$USER/.ccache` folder, and a symlink `$HOME/.ccache -> /mnt/sdb1/$USER/.ccache`.

My question is: Which folders (or subfolders) within $HOME is it reasonable for me to move? Or rather - what is a rule of thumb I could use for making this decision?

Notes:

- No need to mention small/tiny folders, I only care about folders which typically take up hundreds of MB or more.
- Of course you can only mention folders one would find in a home directory on a typical Fedora installation; my personally-created custom folders are irrelevant to this question (and suppose they don't take up much space).

Comment: Use something like `du --max-depth=1` to check what the big subdirectories in your case are? I would suppose any caches for the web browser might be largish, and really not in need of backing up.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Of course I've done that; I'm only asking about the large(ish) folders to begin with. The thing is, some folders might be important to keep in case of failure, like, say, `.thunderbird` which holds your mail, or perhaps `.local` etc.

Comment: This is hard to answer for your specific case without knowing which directories are large enough for you to consider moving them. Perhaps you could edit your question with the `du` output? From the sound of things, other than things like `~/.cache` it is just a personal question of what you want backed up.